# Help with Wire Nut sizes

Tags: electrical, switch, dimmer-switch, wire

I need two sizes of wire nuts but I can't find anything that specify the work/wire load that I need.

Plus I wanna swap out my backstab/push in connectors with Wire nuts cause people saying it's not really a recommended way of tying lines together

I'm looking for wire nuts that support

1. 4x 14 AWG solid copper
2. 6x 14 AWG solid copper

Comment: http://www.idealindustries.ca/products/wire_termination/twist-on/twister.php between tan and grey they are about the only two you'll ever need, only get Ideal branded and not a cheap imitation.    (( by the way you didn't know it when you asked, but this question is both religious and political will likely receive answers passionate answers ))

Comment: I prefer 3M twist on wire connectors.

Comment: You could also get push-in connectors like [these](https://www.idealind.com/ideal-electrical/us/en/products/wire-termination/20-push-in-wire-connectors/in-sure-push-in-wire-connectors.aspx). They come in a variety of sizes, meaning number of ports, and typically accept #20 up to #12 wire.

Answer (score 3):

Red, as per this [Ideal Industries datasheet](http://www.idealind.com/content/pdfs/specsheets/b-twist-spec-sheet.pdf).

Comment: Reds don't work for 6 splices

Comment: I have to respectfully disagree RT.

Comment: I'm looking at Gardner Bender wire nuts says 3 or 4 #14

Comment: Reds do up to 5 12's, or 6 14's. I guess I can go find a link. One sec...

Comment: Please do, thx.

Comment: Hope this works. Sorry, I'm a newb to Gnome Web.. :  http://www.idealind.com/content/pdfs/specsheets/b-twist-spec-sheet.pdf

Comment: My 35-year-old box of red Scotchloks states 2 to 4 #14 an 2 to 4 #12. In practice I don't use these reds for four #12. I use the Grey Scotchloks for four #12. The color is not an official designation and the capacity of a red color coded twist-on connector varies from manufacturer to manufacturer. 3M now has new dual color connectors.

Comment: Ol' Scotchlocks, wow. Makes my fingers ache just saying the word. B-caps are where it's at, millions of arthritic joints agree.. ;)

Answer (score 3):

It totally depends on what the manufacturer has **listed** the wire-nuts for. The manufacturer tells Underwriter's Labs which several dozen size combinations they'd like their twist-connector tested for... and then UL torture-tests each of those combinations, resulting in a UL listing.

And somewhere on the web is a super-boring spreadsheet of *each and every single one* of the combinations for which that twist-connector is listed.

Those docs can be a bit hard to find on the web, they love to steer you toward the *color brochure* which armwaves something like `2x#16 to 3x#10` - which doesn't tell you a darned thing.  An email to your vendor's support department ought to get you the link.

For instance, Ideal chooses to *not* list their "red" wire nuts for 6x14AWG.  No idea why not.   Somebody does.  If it's not listed, you can't use it - the end.